# How to use multiple parameters with fittype in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parameters

I have a 1000x2 data file that I'm using for this problem.

I am supposed to fit the data with Acos(wt + phi). t is time, which is the first column in the data file, i.e. the independent variable. I need to find the fit parameters (A, f, and phi) and their uncertainties.

My code is as follows:

```
%load initial data file
data = load('hw_fit_cos_problem.dat');
t = data(:,1); %1st column is t (time)
x = t;
y = data(:,2); %2nd column is y (signal strength)

%define fitting function
f = fittype('A*cos(w*x + p)','coefficients','A','problem',{'w','p'});

% check fit parameters
coeffs = coeffnames(f);

%fit data
[A] = fit(x,y,f)

disp('confidence interval/errorbars');
ci = confint(A)
```

which yields 4 different error messages that I don't understand.

Error Messages:

Error using fit>iAssertNumProblemParameters (line 1113)
Missing problem parameters. Specify the values as a cell array with one element for each problem parameter
in the fittype.

Error in fit>iFit (line 198)
iAssertNumProblemParameters( probparams, probnames( model ) );

Error in fit (line 109)
[fitobj, goodness, output, convmsg] = iFit( xdatain, ydatain, fittypeobj, ...

Error in problem2 (line 14)
[A] = fit(x,y,f)

Comment: Please provide the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code

```
f = fittype('A*cos(w*x + p)','coefficients','A','problem',{'w','p'});
```

specifies `A` as a "coefficient" in the model, and the values `w` and `p` as "problem" parameters.

Thus, the fitting toolbox expects that you will provide some more information about `w` and `p`, and then it will vary `A`. When no further information about `w` and `p` was provided to the fitting tool, that resulted in an error.

I am not sure  of the goal of this project, or why `w` and `p` were designated as problem parameters. However, one simple solution is to allow the toolbox to treat `A`, `w`, and  `p` as "coefficients", as follows:

```
f = fittype('A*cos(w*x + p)','coefficients', {'A', 'w', 'p'});
```

In this case, the code will not throw an error, and will return 95% confidence intervals on `A`, `w`, and `p`.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward answer to your question is that the error "Missing problem parameters" is generated because you have identified w and p as problem-specific fixed parameters,
but you have not told the fit function what these fixed values are.

You can do this by changing the line

[A] = fit(x,y,f)

to

[A]=fit(x,y,f,'problem',{100,0.1})

which supplies the values w=100 and p=0.1 in the fit.  This should resolve the errors you specified (all 4 error messages result from this error)

In general specifying some of the quantities in your fit equation as problem-specific fixed parameters might be a valid thing to do - for example if you have determined them independently and have good reason to believe the values you obtained to be reliable.  In this case, you might know the frequency w in this way, but you most probably won't know the phase p, so that should be a fit coefficient.

Hope that helps.